# Alert not showing the updated state in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an application where I have a form in which user enters a value in text field and then that value is passed to the child component when submit button is clicked. The state of the variable to be passed into the child (var1) is set with every change in the input box, so the changed value passes to the child with each change. To prevent that, I declared one more variable (finalVar1) and set its state to that of the var1 only when submit button is clicked and pass finalVar1 instead. However, when I try to alert(finalVar1) after setting its state, it is always blank even when var1 is not.
Here is my code

```js
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {var1:"",finalVar1:""};
        this.setVar1 = this.setVar1.bind(this)


      } 

    setVar1(e){

        this.setState({ var1: e.target.value });
    }

    submitClick(){
        this.setState({ finalVar1: this.state.var1 });
        alert(this.state.var1 +" "+this.state.finalVar1) //var1 is not blank, finalVar1 is blank
    }
    render(){
        return (<div>
        <form>

            <input  type="text" onChange={ this.setVar1 }/>

            <button onClick={this.submitClick.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
            <Child var1={this.state.finalVar1} />
        </form>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, state updates are asynchronous, which means trying to console.log or alert the next value *just* after setting it doesn't work. Class-based components' `setState` function allows for a second [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) parameter guaranteed to be called *after* state has been updated.

```
submitClick(){
  this.setState(
    { finalVar1: this.state.var1 },
    () => alert(this.state.var1 + " " + this.state.finalVar1)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `setState` is synchronous, it takes a callback as its second argument. We can use the setState callback to keep `state-handling` close to set-setting. When this callback fires, this.state is the updated state.

```js
submitClick() {
  this.setState({
    finalVar1: this.state.var1
  }, () => (alert(this.state.var1 + " " + this.state.finalVar1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass callvack in setstae. this.setstate( statework, ()=> alert('hello'))